# mounting loop not working with UUID

Tags: mount, fstab, loop-device

I have created a `loop` device and added it to `/etc/fstab`

I got its `UUID` from the output of the `blkid` command (it does print a `UUID` for the particular device after running `mkfs.ext4 /path/to/loop`)

However **despite** the fact that after editing `/etc/fstab` the command `mount -a` was successful, the system after the reboot halted.

Insted the following entry in `/etc/fstab` seems to do the job:

```
/path/to/loop    /mountpoint    ext4 loop 0 0
```

Why replacing `/path/to/loop` with `UUID` breaks things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only block devices have UUIDs (that can be found).

A file is not a block device, the loop device turns it into one.

So for the UUID of an image file to be found, the loop device must exist first.

However, your fstab entry is a loop mount, i.e. the loop device is only created when you mount it (and immediately removed on umount), so it does not exist before you mount it (and after you umount it), and so... the UUID is not found because the loop device does not exist.

For loop mounts, it's completely fine to specify the file by path.

Otherwise you'd need an init script that sets up loop devices before attempting to mount them (and then get rid of the loop mount option).